# What is the difference between SELECT * and returning all columns by specfying each in the Select statement / Union query returns Duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table structure (Table name Notifications)

```
   _id | NotificationFor | DateToNotify | isExtraOrdinary |
   NotificationData | TypeNotification | FriendsName |
   RadioType | PrimaryId
```

I have exactly the same schema for the table called as NotificationsCron, however sometimes the second table has exactly the same records at the Notifications table. I use the following query to fetch records:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Notifications
      WHERE TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3'
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM NotificationsCron
      WHERE TypeNotification <> 'Event' AND RadioType <> '3'
     ) T 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0) > SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0),
         SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0);
```

However I am getting duplicates when I use the above, I went through similar problems on the internet and found out the UNION ALL returns duplicates whereas UNION does not. Which is not working in my case, the second important point I came across is to specify each column name instead of SELECT * I want to know how does that make a difference -- Interested in knowing how that works at basic level?

Here is the image of the NotificationsCron table:

[image: Table NotificationsCron]

Here is one image from the Notifications table:

[image: Table Notifications]

Comment: Can you show us the result of your query?

Comment: Sure give me a minute and I will run this.

Comment: Your "select *" most likely includes both ID fields, which may be not equal. When you queried as "select <fieldlist>", did you include both ID fields? No?

Comment: It seems that is the problem, my PrimaryId of NotificationsCron is equal to the _id field in the Notifications table. Can you please provide more insight into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the second important point I came across is to specify each column
>   name instead of SELECT * I want to know how does that make a
>   difference

Later down the road, someone adds a field to the table. Any queries that use "SELECT *" suddenly gain a new field. Sometimes this is correct. Sometimes this yields unexpected results. In most cases, it is a better practice to always explicitly name the columns rather than use wildcards.

Secondly, if you don't actually need all columns, you can improve performance by limiting the columns returned. Even further, in some databases, a query can be satisfied by an INDEX without going to the table, so if you use column lists, it allows that optimization to happen. With SELECT * it cannot.

Comment: So there is no performance issue here? Only that to take care of the future we have to correct the present?

Comment: Depends. select * vs select <list all columns> is equivalent in performance. The performance difference comes into play if you use a subset of columns.